# QGIS plugin: set the position of the featureForm

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pyqt, python-3

Im developing QGIS plugin (Python3)

to open the featureForm (depending on some of my conditions (matching geometries,...))I use this code:

```
            layer = self.iface.activeLayer()
            features = layer.getFeatures()

            for feat in features:
                geom_poly = feat.geometry()
                if self.feature.geometry().intersects(geom_poly):
                    layer.selectByIds([feat.id()])
                    f = feat
            self.iface.openFeatureForm(layer, f, True)
```

the code works correctly, what I want is to set the position of the featureForm

how can I "catch" featureForm and use something like QDialog.move(x, y)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution, I used:

> virtual QgsAttributeDialog* QgisInterface::getFeatureForm   (   QgsVectorLayer *    l,
>   QgsFeature &    f 
>   )

Returns a feature form for a given feature.

*Parameters:*

*l* :The layer for which the dialog will be created

*f* :The feature for which the dialog will be created

*Here is a code if someone else needs it:*

```
   form = self.iface.getFeatureForm(layer, f) # QgsAttributeDialog
   form.move(0,0)
   form.show()
```